# 32 bit or 64 bit becauce of upgrade of RAM?

Tags: ram

On an old Dell PC that originally ran Windows XP 32 bit that I erased the Windows XP 32 bit and installed Ubuntu 32 bit on with less than 2 gigs of RAM. I would like to upgrade the RAM above 2 gigs. So now that if I have more than 2 gigs of RAM should I then **also** upgrade the Ubuntu to the 64 bit OS?

Comment: you need not unless you plan to run 1 program which will use more than 3.5 gb linux has an extension which will allow you to use 4gb of mem

Comment: Quick question - does your Dell actually support a 64-bit OS?

Comment: The old Dell Windows XP was originally a 32 bit OS, I thought if I upgraded the RAM (to 8 gigs) I would need to use the 64 bit Ubuntu OS. I guess it would still be okay using the 32 bit?

Comment: @DracNoc most computers bought about 10 years back (except some core duo/M and a few early Atom CPUs) support 64 bit, so it's not a thing to worry

Comment: @Ric it's better to use 64-bit Ubuntu to utilizes all the new features. PAE is very bad https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/

Answer (score 1):

With regards to RAM, the only benefit is when you have more than 4gb installed.  Be sure that your motherboard will actually support more than 4gb, then go for 64bit.

Either way though my opinion on 32bit vs 64bit is that running 32bit is like wasting half of your processor. Your OS can only handle 32 bits at a time but your processor can do double that. Mathematically speaking that is true.

I have but one question. Why have you not gone 64bit already?

Comment: The old Windows XP computer originally came with 1 gig of RAM. But the mother board has four slots to add more RAM.

Comment: That is the age of computers where there is a grey area. Manufacturers often installed 32 bit on 64 bit processors and 32 bit processors because it was cheaper and XP64 was so new.  Before you try to install 64 bit double check that your processor is 64 bit.